# Setting Pagination on REST API copy source in azure data factory for shopify

Tags: rest, pagination, shopify, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy shopify data from the rest API and was able to get the 1st page of data, however I cannot figure out how to set the pagination. The pagination is coming in the header response see shopify documentation below which states there is a link segment which contains the next page link.
https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest

I have it set to this on the source tab pagination settings in ADF but this returns an error:
[image: ADF Source Settings]

ADF ERROR: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestSourceCallFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The HttpStatusCode 404 indicates failure. Request URL: https://joyfolie.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/%3Chttps://joyfolie.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/products.json?limit=50&page_info=eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NjI0ODcyMjEwNDkwLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiKk5FVyogQmFlIFNraXJ0IGluIE9jaHJlIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9%3E;%20rel=%22next%22 Response payload:{"errors":"Not Found"},Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,' Source Pipeline Copy Shopify Products

THis is how the link looks in the response header

https://joyfolie.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=50&page_info=eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NjI0ODcyMjEwNDkwLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiKk5FVyogQmFlIFNraXJ0IGluIE9jaHJlIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9; rel="next"
[image]

Comment: did you find a way around this ?

Comment: Not at all! But I have not been able to spend much time with it